# time specific code in MT4

Tags: mt4

In MT4 custom indicator/EA, how do I work with time please?

E.g every day 08:05, I would like to check the High/Low of this 5min bar. I don't know how to work with this 5 minute period only.

Many thanks
Vic

Answer (score 0):

```
//inputs:
input int InpMinuteYouNeed = 5;
input int InpHourYouNeed = 8;

void OnTick(){
   if(Hour()==InpHourYouNeed && Minute()==InpMinuteYouNeed){

   }
}
```

Also you may found the following functions interesting:

```
 datetime time = StrToTime("8:05");
 int hourYouNeed = TimeHour(time);
 int minuteYouNeed = TimeMinute(time);
```

then use these values same as InpHourYouNeed but of course they must be global or in struct. This must be enough for the first time.